# Get softmax output and raw output of the last layer of a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

When creating a neural network for image classification, I want to get the classification on one hand and the raw output on the other hand to determine if the image really contains one of the images I want to classify or not. If not then the raw output should contain very low values for all classes. But if the image really contains one of the objects that I want to classify, then the raw output should have a high value for one of the neurons.

Assuming I have the following code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(80, 80, 3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

How would I get the raw output of the last dense layer?

Comment: If raw output you are referring the logits, then don't use softmax here. You can use it manually later. Also note that, if you do so, in training time you may need to specify from logit to True.

Answer (score 1):

You can use functional API and implement your model in a next way:

```
  inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(80, 80, 3))
  x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(inputs)
  x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
  # here you can get raw output
  logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(x)
  model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=inputs, 
    outputs={
      'logits': logits,
      'predictions': tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    }
  )
  model.summary()
```

After that, your model will have two outputs in dictionary format. Beware that you can't use a simple loss function like `categorical_crossentropy` because it will try to minimize loss for both outputs. You need to use `losses` argument in `compile` method to specify the loss for each output. For example:

```
  model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss={
      # ignore logits loss
      'logits': lambda y_true, y_pred: 0.0,
      'predictions': tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    })
```

And your fit would look like this:

```
  model.fit(
    x_train,
    {
      'logits': y_train,
      'predictions': y_train
    },
    epochs=10
  )
```